# Spring boot - Serving static content

Tags: spring-boot

I have issues configuring Spring boot 1.2.0.M1 to serve static content.
As soon as I add a **@RestController** component in my application, the static content is not displayed and I get the *whitelabel* error page instead. My resources are in the *src/main/resources/static* folder.

I followed the instructions at http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot and managed to have them displayed by setting the *ResourceHandlerRegistry* priority to -1. But i guess it is not the standard and right way to do it. It seems that the handler of the REST resources takes priority over the resource handler registry. Is there a possibility to configure the handler for rest resource to be used for a sub-context only like */api* ?

**Update:**

I have put the DispatcherServlet in debug and I have better understanding on why this is happening but still not sure what would be the best way to deal with it.
I have noticed that the following handlers are registered in the Dispatch servlet in the respective order by default :

1. SimpleUrlHandlerMapping -> favico
2. RequestMappingHandlerMapping -> annotated @RestController methods registered
3. SimpleUrlHanderMapping -> / (home page handling ?)
4. BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping
5. SimpleUrlHandlerMapping -> handles resources configured in the resources registry
6. WebMVCConfigurationSupport handler

When I perform a POST on the REST resource 2. handles it.
When I perform a GET on a static resource 2. throws a *HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException* because it cannot find the resource (in its handleNoMatch method).

If i change the priorities using *ResourceHandlerRegistry#setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)*;  5. is placed before 2. but in this case i cannot perform a POST /user/api intended for my REST resource, it is not matched as a resource (i have configured a /** pattern for the resource handler).

If i compare to what node.js/express does for instance is that you configure routes for your controllers and if none matches the request, the request is handled by the handler for static resources or templates.

Do you know how if it is possible through annotation to have the 2 (i.e RequestMappingHandlerMapping ) not throw an exception but just pass the request to the next handler in the chain in case of no-match ?
I'd like avoiding having a specific context (/static for static resources).

**Update 2**:

Actually it was just a misconfiguration of my annotated REST controller **@RestController**
I configured the path in the value attribute of the annotation that is not meant for that but to store the controller's name
I forgot to add the **@RequestMapping** therefore the handler RequestMappingHandlerMapping was enabled for any url path and the get request did not match any annotated methods, therefore it returned an error.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you could share a complete project?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same misbehaviour, but (down to the debugging). But I have an empty @RestController and a @RequestMapping(name="rest/bla"). And I'm still receiving the 405 errors. What did I differently from you?